# How to convert this function to an ES6 (arrow syntax) IIFE function?

Tags: javascript

I'm looking to convert this function to an IIFE function using arrow function syntax. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
  function overrideDefaultValueIcon() {
    const defaultValueRow = document.getElementsByClassName('field-default_value');
    const defaultValueText = defaultValueRow[0].getElementsByClassName('readonly')[0]; 

    switch (defaultValueRow[0].getElementsByTagName('img')[0].alt) {
      case 'True':
        defaultValueText.innerHTML += ' <span style="color:green";>True</span>';
        break;
      case 'False':
        defaultValueText.innerHTML += ' <span style="color:red";>False</span>';
        break;
      default:
        defaultValueText.innerHTML += '';
    }
  }

  overrideDefaultValueIcon();
```

Comment: Why would it need to be an arrow function? Normal `function` IIFEs are just as fine if you don't need `this`.

Comment: If you're going to use an arrow function for an IIFE, why not just use a code block? `{...}` As long as you don't use `var`, you'll have the same effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, and use querySelector and `? :` to cut down on some code

```
(() => {
  const row = document.querySelector('.field-default_value');
  const { alt } = row.querySelector('img');
  row.querySelector('.readonly').innerHTML = alt === 'True'
    ? ' <span style="color:green";>True</span>'
    : alt === 'False'
      ? ' <span style="color:red";>False</span>'
      : '';
})();
```

Comment: I would suggest to avoid nesting ternary operators.

Comment: It works and it's more concise than the alternative. If one doesn't like it it's easy to change.

Comment: Think how it will look if another case appear.

Comment: If it gets *more* nested it's an issue, but given the number of branches in the code in the question I prefer this way.

Comment: @KKK: Nested conditional operators can look bad, so don't nest them badly. When they're clean as shown above, there's nothing wrong. But suggesting that something shouldn't be done because it *could* be done badly, would mean that people shouldn't program at all.